# QDebug on Android - write directly to the ADB console stream

Tags: android, c++, qt

When using QDebug stream (like this: `QDebug()<<"something"`), output looks like this in the ADB console:

```
D/QAppName(18064): ../lib/log/LOGGER.cpp:25 (virtual void QTLog::Put(const char*, int)): something
```

I have my own library, `LOGGER.cpp` that is responsible for adding `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, thread ID and function name to the output. This causes second issue, fragments of one library message get scattered on lines, as `QDebug` considers each fragment a single message (removed paths for brevity):

```
D/QApp(18064): [stuff stuff stuff]: I
D/QApp(18064): [stuff stuff stuff]:
D/QApp(18064): [stuff stuff stuff]: 2015-11-26 14:10:06:754
D/QApp(18064): [stuff stuff stuff]:  [
D/QApp(18064): [stuff stuff stuff]: TCPlient          #0
D/QApp(18064): [stuff stuff stuff]: ]
D/QApp(18064): [stuff stuff stuff]: sigConnect
D/QApp(18064): [stuff stuff stuff]:
D/QApp(18064): [stuff stuff stuff]: test MT
```

That output was supposed to look like this:

```
I 2015-11-26 14:10:06:754 [TCPlient          #0] sigConnect test MT
```

So I need direct access to the ADB output stream, either via Qt or otherwise. This solution should work on IOS as well, if possible.